# Allow Users to upload videos to WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, video, upload, gravity-forms-plugin

I am looking for a solution to allow for users to upload video content to my WordPress website. Essentially, I want users to be able to vlog.

Currently, I have gravity forms installed that handles the front end for the vlog form and it does support video files but when I try submitting it will just load forever.
I probably can’t support video uploads on my site and it will probably just slow things down for me.

Is there a work around to allowing users to upload video content to my site with WordPress?
Can a URL from another source be used in an iframe maybe?

Thanks

Comment: Doing it yourself is a huge mess, we don't know the formats people are going to upload, if they're too big or too small, what codec they use, you probably don't have horsepower to convert videos and have standard formats for your videoplayer (another headache)... Just host it elsewhere, let them do the conversion and user their player (YouTube, Streamable, Vimeo, etc)

Comment: @brasofilo what would be the proper flow for that?

Comment: Too many steps mate, one would need to write a full blown tutorial... you can try to find one or research step by step. Research tips: 1) use "keyword1 keyword2 site:stackoverflow.com" on Google, normally it gives better results than the internal search; 2) use tags and advanced operators when searching inside SO or [wordpress.se]

Comment: Right now, your question falls into at least two off-topic closing reasons: too broad and asking for recommendations. I closed it as duplicate of many good examples for you to start. Your Gravity form would have to be coupled with a WP solution or a third party solution. When you try to implement something and can't get the code to work, then you have a good question to post here. Good luck!